# Multisite - create new site with precreated pages, menu etc

Tags: multisite

I'm developing a site, where users will be creating their own sub-sites.

On new site creation, I would need to prefill it with some Pages, Menu settings etc. Is there an easy way to do this, any hook to use?

Answer (score 1):

The proper hook for that is `wpmu_new_blog`. I will describe how we do that in [Multilingual Press Pro](http://marketpress.com/product/multilingual-press-pro/). Our code is actually rather complex; I will extract the most important points.

We offer an option to select *any* existing blog as a template for the new blog. The nice part is that you can edit the template content, customize the theme, activate plugins … like in any other blog. No need to update the code when you change your mind about the default content later.

For your use case, you can just create *one* template blog and take the blog ID.

```
add_action( 'wpmu_new_blog', function( $blog_id ) {
    // copy the template blog here
});
```

What happens in the callback?

1. We get the prefix for the template blog (ID 44):

   ```
   switch_to_blog( 44 );
   $template_prefix = $wpdb->prefix;
   restore_current_blog();
   ```
2. We erase the fresh tables for the new blog and copy the content from the template blog.

   ```
   foreach ( $tables as $table )
   {
       // empty the tables
       $wpdb->query( 'TRUNCATE TABLE ' . $wpdb->prefix . $table );
       // insert template content
       $wpdb->query( "INSERT INTO $wpdb->prefix$table SELECT * FROM $template_prefix$table" );
   }
   ```
3. We restore the most important options for the new blog (`blogname`, `home`, `admin_email` and so on) and rename the `user_roles` to match the current blog.
4. Then we copy the attachments. These are … not simple. `wp_upload_dir()` is not reliable after `switch_to_blog()`. You have to add some workarounds to get the correct paths. This is actually a separate class with 250 lines. :)

There are other issues like domain mapping plugins, custom plugin tables and some minor compatibility problems with other plugins using the same hook or themes and plugins expecting an installation call. They shouldn’t bother you when you just need a solution for one site.

Comment: Thanks, ths was really helpfull! Can you give me some more details on the attachments? Or, do you offer a separate plugin for this?

Comment: @user1049961 On subdomains, `wp_upload_dir()[ 'baseurl' ]` is _sometimes_ wrong, it has to be adjusted. And you have to parse `_wp_attachment_metadata` to get the paths for all file sizes (thumbnail etc.). This part is of our plugin is released under GPL, but you get it only with the Pro version.